# Firebase Storage: call random folder?

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a labeling tool for ML, and I want to be able to display the contents of a random folder on a React app so I can label them.I was thinking of finding the amount of folders, searching through the last available folder, and then delete from database. Repeat on refresh. Is this possible? I haven't been able to find out how to return the amount of folders in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
var folders = [];
// Create a reference under which you want to list
var listRef = storageRef.child('path/to/files');

// Find all the prefixes and items.
listRef.listAll().then(function(res) {
  res.prefixes.forEach(function(folderRef) {
    // All the prefixes under listRef.
    folders.push(folderRef);
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
});

var selected = []
// Select N=5 at random
for (i=0; i < 5 && folders.length > 0 ; i++){
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * folders.length)
  selected.push(folders[index])
  folders.splice(index, 1);
}
```

You can list the files/folders inside a bucket path. [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files). And select one at random of that list.

And similarly with [delete files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files).